# Laravel - export to excell on different cells

Tags: laravel, export, cell

In my controller I have a function call to download a .xls file after my table is filtered. I get the variable with `session::get`

This is the dd($data);

[image]

The download button works fine. I just can't get each field to fill a different cell, like ID - A1, Name - B1... and below the respective fields.

This is my controller function:

```
public function downloadExcel($type)
{
    $data1 = array();

    $data = Session::get('data');
    //dd($data);

    return Excel::create('teste', function($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but you are not using an array, but an collection. Could you try to convert it to an array? And I do not fully understand you question. Could you add an image of the excel document your are now getting back?

Comment: @JanWytze the excel file is filled but not the way i want. each array position fills one cell. like all user data goes to one cell. I wanted that each field of the array/collection goes to different cells

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it. I used this tutorial:
 http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/19/exporting-laravel-data-to-an-excel-spreadsheet/

I needed a foreach inside a foreach to reach my values. This way they will go accordingly.